# How can I enable my laptop's built-in mic while headphones are plugged in?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, microphone

My headset's microphone broke. So, on Windows 10 I used the Bang & Olufsen drivers for my Omen HP 15-ax033dx laptop to enable "multistreaming" which enables the ability to use both the internal and (broken) headset mics at the same time. Is there anyway to do this on Ubuntu (More specifically Neon KDE) and or install the Windows 10 HP audio drivers?